# Issue with incremental numbers to create unique names in cloned elements

Tags: javascript, auto-increment, increment, cloning

Onclick I am cloning checkboxes so client can order as much as they want of the original offer. I have two issues right now:

1) Adding a unique number to original name. The way it works right now :

I get this a_1, a_12, a_123, etc.

instead of this  a_1, a_2, a_3, etc.

2) The other issue is that the increment for textbox "b" does not start at 1 but where the previous one (a) finishes. I want it to start at one.

Thank for your help, here is my code :

```
c = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
var currentNameAttr = $(this).attr('name'); 
var newNameAttr = (currentNameAttr+(++c))
var cloned;
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
$(this).parent().parent().parent().clone(true).insertAfter(this)
$(this).prop('checked', false)
$(this).attr('name', newNameAttr)
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this line: `var newNameAttr = (currentNameAttr+(++c))`. What happens is that it checks what `currentNameAttr` is with `$(this).attr('name')` and adds c to it. However, you're not removing the last c, so what you need to do is this:

```
 c = 0;
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
      var baseName = "a_"; 
      var newNameAttr = baseName + c;
           c++;
      var cloned;

      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(this).parent().parent().parent().clone(true).insertAfter(this)
           $(this).prop('checked', false)
           $(this).attr('name', newNameAttr)
      }
 })
```

This way it will always add `c`, which will be an integer greater than 0, to `baseName`, which will be "a_" or whatever you set it to. Each time you go through this function, it will increment c, so that the next time it won't assign the same id.

Comment: Thanks @Luxelin it works. Although, I like to keep the key name in the NewNameAttr. How could I do it? (My Key names correspond to clients Products Id numbers).

Comment: @user3371049 Is there a basic format to how these work? As in, can you always just remove all the numbers from the end? If so, you can use regex to grab all but the last part (all but the #) and then add a new number.